# Which components,modules and plugin i should install in joomla 2.5 except the already installed extensions.

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I have started working on joomla and i want to know which Extensions i should install while using Joomla platform except the default installed extensions in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right you don't have to install anything at all to start working in joomla. You can start blogging or component development or whatever task you are supposed to.

It really depends on the purpose of your website. If you check this ***[link](http://www.joomlaport.com/joomla-extension-reviews/10-free-joomla-extensions-i-cant-live-without.html)*** you might find some important extensions which might help you out.